# Hide price from form of add product in BO Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price

I want to create all my configurable product without any price and I don't want to see the price information on the whole website.
How to proceed step by step, please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should create a plugin to hide product price, and then edit some templates like

> {magento_dir}/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml
>   {magento_dir}/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/minicart.phtml

and anything else using `$product->getPrice()`

With plugin, you can reference my example:

**1. app/code/Training/Test/etc/frontend/di.xml**

> ```
> <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
>   <plugin name="training_final_price_box" type="Training\Test\Plugin\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox"/>
> </type>
> ```

**2. app/code/Training/Test/Plugin/Catalog/Pricing/Render/FinalPriceBox.php**

```
class FinalPriceBox
{
    function aroundToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, \Closure $proceed)
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Regards

Comment: thanks for your replay but i did not understand the utility of the class Final Box : is it an override of something or just some clss to hide price in specific place ???